# Set custom route using OData 8

Tags: .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Recently I updated to OData 8.0.10. I added this in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddRouting();
services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => 
opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()).Filter().Select().OrderBy().Count());
```

where

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Project>("Project");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

I have this small controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 20)]
    public IQueryable<Project> GetAsync()
    {
        var projects = _projectRepository.GetAll();
        return projects;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetProjectById")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsyncById(long id)
    {
        var project = await _projectService.GetProjectByIDAsync(id);
        return Ok(project);
    }

    [HttpPatch("{id}", Name = "PatchProjectById")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PatchProject(long id, [FromBody] ProjectPatchDetails projectPatch)
    {
        var project = await _projectRepository.GetAsync(id);
        var updated = await _projectService.UpdateProjectAsync(id, project, projectPatch);
        return Ok(updated);
    }
}
```

that has three endpoints, one of them is annotated by `[EnableQuery]` and the rest aren't. When I access `api/project?$count=true&$skip=0&$orderby=CreateDate%20desc`, I get a paged info (20 records) but I don't get the @odata.context and @odata.count. If I access `/odata/project?$count=true&$skip=0&$orderby=CreateDate%20desc`, with `odata/` prefix, it gives me @odata.context and @odata.count. I tried changing `AddRouteComponents` to `AddRouteComponents("api", GetEdmModel())` but in this case I get the following error:

> "The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: MyApp.Api.Controllers.ProjectController.GetAsync (MyApp.Api) MyApp.Api.Controllers.ProjectController.GetAsync (MyApp.Api)"

I have multiple questions in this case:

1. Is there a way to reroute odata to api, make /odata prefix as /api and make it work?
2. Should I make another controller that will store all OData tagged actions and on this way maybe workaround this as a solution, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@anthino

1. Is there a way to reroute odata to api, make /odata prefix as /api and make it work?

if you add 'opt.AddRouteComponents("api", GetEdmModel())', remember to remove
[Route("api/[controller]")] and other attribute routings

2. Should I make another controller that will store all OData tagged actions and on this way maybe workaround this as a solution, if possible?

Basically, it's better to create two controllers, one for odata, the other for others. In your scenario, you mixed them together. You should be careful about this. You can use 'app.UseODataRouteDebug()' middleware to help you debug.

Comment: I'm adding some flavor to this answer. Depending on the scenario, I use 1.) different controllers for OData vs regular API and 2.) hybrid (use both in one controller). It really depends on how big the controller will be in order to keep the readable, maintainable and usable.

I have mostly hybrid because I specifically only use OData for queries, while all POST, PUT, DELETE are regular API endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ProjectController` should be inheriting from `ODataController` not `ControllerBase`. With the ODataController, you should get the `context url` and the `@odata.count`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).